# Can't find selectors when headless is enabled - Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I created a simple puppeteer script using headless recorder extension, but it's not working when I run it.

```
TimeoutError: waiting for selector `.a-button-stack > #atc-declarative > #submit.add-to-cart #add-to-cart-button` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

I've also tried inspecting elements myself. So if you go to that amazon url and inspect button, I tried the following, but it always times out.

`await page.waitForSelector('#add-to-cart-button')`

`await page.waitForSelector('.a-button-stack')`

`await page.waitForSelector('.a-button-input a-declarative')`

How can I locate the correct selectors when headless is enabled? There must be a way otherwise how would a headless browser be able to navigate. I'm guessing that this generated script from `headless-recorder` chrome extension is for when headless is set to false. I could be wrong though. The goal is very simple. Go to the amazon product page, click add to cart and then click view cart. I appreciate any help!

amazon.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const randomUseragent = require('random-useragent');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()

    await page.goto('https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Essentials-Full-Zip-Hooded-Sweatshirt/dp/B075JW9CYR?ref_=Oct_DLandingS_D_cf757c44_63&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&th=1&psc=1')

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 969 })

    await page.waitForSelector('.a-button-stack > #atc-declarative > #submit\.add-to-cart #add-to-cart-button')
    await page.click('.a-button-stack > #atc-declarative > #submit\.add-to-cart #add-to-cart-button')

    await navigationPromise

    await page.waitForSelector('.nav-right > #nav-tools > #nav-cart #nav-cart-count')
    await page.click('.nav-right > #nav-tools > #nav-cart #nav-cart-count')

    await navigationPromise

    await browser.close()
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
await page.goto('https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Essentials-Full-Zip-Hooded-Sweatshirt/dp/B075JW9CYR?ref_=Oct_DLandingS_D_cf757c44_63&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&th=1&psc=1')
await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("body")');
```

Comment: If I only add that then it works. How can I drill down further? If I add this after ```await page.waitForSelector('.a-button-stack > #atc-declarative > #submit\.add-to-cart #add-to-cart-button')``` it fails. I also tried drilling down from body ```await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("body > .a-button-stack > #atc-declarative > #submit\.add-to-cart #add-to-cart-button")');``` but it fails.

Comment: Try simple one to see if works: `await page.waitForSelector('.a-button-stack');`